# Действие при завершении клипа в AudioSource

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать, чтобы выполнялось какое-то действие при завершении клипа в AudioSource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
public AudioClip someClip;

 
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(playSound());
}
 
IEnumerator playSound() {    
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = someClip;
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(someClip.length);
    
    doAdditionalCationAfterClipFinish();    
}

void doAdditionalCationAfterClipFinish() {
    // что-то сделать
}
```

Comment: 2 ошибки:
'AudioSource' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no accessible extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'AudioSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

и

Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.AudioSource' to 'UnityEngine.AudioClip'

Comment: @KlimeLime да. в самом начале надо было `public AudioClip someClip;` а не `public AudioSource someClip;` Поправил

Comment: Всё работает отлично!